# why can't I encode output str from soup.findAll to utf-8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
html_req_url = 'http://www.superfix.com/'
html_content = urllib.urlopen(html_req_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
html_title = soup.findAll('title')
print html_title
```

here is the output:

```
ascii
[<title>SUPERFIX\u5b98\u7f51 \u2013 \u5b89\u5168\u4fbf\u6377\u7684\u624b\u673a\u7ef4\u4fee\u670d\u52a1</title>]
```

I using PyCharm in my Mac, and I can't encode any output str from `soup.findAll('title')`, but `print soup` is normal.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

`soup.findAll()` (or `soup.find_all()`, the new name) returns a list of [`Tag` objects](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag). These are not themselves text and can't be encoded.

There is only one `<title>` tag in a HTML document, so use `soup.find()`, then use [`Tag.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to extract the text contents:

```
title_tag = soup.find('title')
if title_tag is not None:
    title = title_tag.get_text()
    print title
```

Text in BeautifulSoup is returned as [`NavigableString` objects](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring), a subclass of `unicode`. You can encode those values to UTF-8 as needed.